# Should page size be a mandatory field in paginated APIs?

Tags: api, rest, pagination

Is it a good practice to always require pageSize when making calls to paginated GET API? Or should we assign a default value to the pageSize in case not provided?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a resource - collection (for example `/books/`), it’s good practice to use pagination.

**Rationale** (from Google API guidelines): If an API does not support pagination from the start, supporting it later is troublesome because adding pagination breaks the API's behavior. Clients that are unaware that the API now uses pagination could incorrectly assume that they received a complete result, when in fact they only received the first page.

Then having a pageNumber (an alternative parameter is `offset`) is good practice, but pageSize (an alternative parameter is `limit`) is optional and you can set a default value.

P.S. You can think about online stores. Some let us set page size, some do not let us set page size, but every show where we are (pageNumber).